# 'list' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a MIddleNode function in Python,

```
head = [1,2,3,4,5]

class ListNode(object):
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next

def middleNode(head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    if head.next == None:
        return head
    num = 0
    temp=ListNode(head)
    #  finding size of list
    while temp!=None:
        num = num + 1
        temp=temp.next
 
    # assigning middle node number
    num=(num/2)+1
    # traversing to middle node with head as we are needed to return list from middle node
    while num > 1:
        head=head.next
        num = num -1
    return head

middleNode(head)
```

however I keep getting this error and the .next is there.

What am I missing?

Comment: head is a list (`head = [1,2,3,4,5]`), that has no next attribute

Comment: Why are you calling `middleNode` with `head`, a list, when the type annotation clearly says it expects a `ListNode` object?

Comment: and how do I build a ListNode object with (1,2,3,4,5,6) ?

Answer (score 1):

head is a normal python list, not a linked list.

```
def create_linked_list(lis, node):
if not lis:
    return node
newnode = ListNode(lis[-1],node)
create_linked_list(lis[:-1],newnode)
```

Here is a recursive function which you can use to create a linked list. To get the equivalent of the list [1,2,3,4,5] you should call

```
create_linked_list([1,2,3,4],ListNode(5))
```

This function returns the head of the linked list, which can then be iterated through with .next

Comment: when I print the linked list, it prints None, something I am missing?

Comment: Yes. The class listnode is defined in your code. For it to print anything you must implement __str__() for the class ListNode, where you define how it should be represented as a string that can then be printed. Here is a short article regarding __str__(): geeksforgeeks.org/print-objects-of-a-class-in-python The list exists, even if you can't print it, though.